# Как реализовать таймер в android приложении при помощи TextView?

Tags: android, kotlin

Как можно реализовать таймер в android приложении при помощи TextView. Использовал вариант через CountDownTimer:

```
       object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
         override fun onTick(seconds: Long) {
            val s: Long = seconds % 100
            val m: Long = seconds / 1000 % 1000

            textView4.text = String.format("%02d:%02d", m, s)
        }
```

Но таймер некорректно работает

Comment: Поясните, что значит некорректно работает?

Comment: Секунды начинаются с 99 и отнимаются по 2-3 за тик, когда таймер доходит примерно до 75 секунд отнимается минута

Comment: Я не знаю синтаксис котлина, но могу с ходу предположить что вы не правильно переводите в секунды и минуты.

Comment: Может так: `textView4.text = String.format("%02d:%02d", seconds / 60000, seconds % 60000 / 1000)`

Comment: Да, теперь всё работает корректно, большое спасибл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не верный формат перевода миллисекунд в секунды и минуты.

Правильный код:

```
object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
     override fun onTick(milliseconds: Long) {
        val s: Long = milliseconds % 60000 / 1000
        val m: Long = milliseconds / 60000

        textView4.text = String.format("%02d:%02d", m, s)
    }
```